# Build Python 3.12 statically

Tags: python, python-3.x, build, static-linking

How can I build python 3.12 from source while statically linking at least libc but ideally all dependencies?

So far I have tried setting LDFLAGS="-static" before running the configure script and changing the Setup file (although I'm not sure I did it correctly).

Comment: This is not easy task. I'd look into this project for start: https://github.com/indygreg/python-build-standalone

Comment: Yea, I've trying to do this for days with no luck. The project is interesting, but it's not what I'm looking for. The produced binaries still depend on the system's libc, even if it's an old one. Thanks anyway.